# How can I remove a granite countertop from a wooden vanity?

Tags: granite, vanity, removal

I recently purchased an inexpensive bath vanity from the Home Labyrinth. It included a low-end granite top that is not properly sized for my bathroom. Unexpectedly, out of the box, the granite is sealed to the wooden top of the unassembled vanity. I really like this vanity's wooden cabinets, but I need to replace the granite with a custom cut size and color.

Is there a good way to separate the granite from the wooden vanity without damaging the wood or the granite? The two pieces are very tightly fitted together. I can't seem to squeeze a utility knife between them. Is there a good strategy for separating granite away from a wooden cabinet? Is this something that a granite specialist could handle easily?

I'm starting to think that a sledge hammer might be the only way.

Comment: Can you post a couple of pictures that are showing the top to side wood joint area up inside the cabinet?

Comment: Also can you see if there is any excess adhesive squeezing out between the wood and granite? The typical adhesive for this is usually silicone. Or maybe remake that part of the frame, using the old one as a template.

Comment: Stop! Hammer Time!

Comment: Was being funny in presentation but serious in the recommendation. Granite is substantially more brittle than wood. If you are just going to throw the current top away you can smash it off, chisel away the glued bits that remain and sand away the adhesive. Wear safety goggles and gloves.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get it started somewhere, but a thin wire wrapped on a handle at each end (as for cutting cheese) will normally cut things off if glued with something reasonable (ie, silicone or similar.)

If they epoxied it in place, it's going to be much more difficult. Heat would be my first approach in that case, hoping the stuff softens, or turns out to be hot glue rather than epoxy.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the replies! How can I determine if it is glue vs. epoxy? Underneath, I can see some spots where the sealant has leaked out. The sealant appears to be clear with a very slight orangish tint.

Comment: Is it "hard and brittle" or "rubbery" or some other description of how it feels when you touch it, and/or acts when you grab the excess with a pair of pliers and try to pull it off the surface. Rubbery tends to be silicone or something that acts like it. Brittle could be epoxy, could be hot glue. There's also hot glue that would be too firm to be rubbery but not firm enough to be brittle. In any case, see what a heat gun or hair dryer does to any non-rubbery glue.

Comment: @user685673:  Epoxy is rather expensive and troublesome to use in an assembly line.  It is a reasonable bet that it is construction glue.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the existing granite, a hammer strike near a corner should split the slab and make it easy to wiggle a large flat blade screwdriver to "separate and lift".

To minimize munging the cabinet, place a smallish piece of broken granite beside the next victim and use the former as a fulcrum.